# Convert multi dimensional array to dict without any imports

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have the following csv data:

```
first_name,last_name
tom,hanks
tom,cruise
```

I would like to convert this data as follows:

```
data = {
    'first_name': ['tom','tom'],
    'last_name': ['hanks', 'cruise']
}
```

What would be the best way to do the above (not using a library such as pandas, numpy, or csv).

Comment: Can you use the `csv` module?

Comment: csv module dict reader + defaultdicts are the way to go.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds yea I'd agree but I'm looking to implement a pure python solution as the data may not be an actual valid csv.

Comment: I mean those are pure python, they're standard library. Still, if you don't want to use the `csv` module, you can parse each line with a `line.split(',')` to split on commas, and then append each value in the split list to the corresponding list in the dictionary.

Comment: @timgeb no I'm just saying a solution without using the csv module.

Comment: Why, **why** can't you use the csv module? And what exactly is the issue you are encountering when you attempt to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faking your file:

```
>>> from io import StringIO                                                                                            
>>> file = StringIO('''first_name,last_name 
...: tom,hanks 
...: tom,cruise''')
```

Creating the dict:

```
>>> data = [(k, []) for k in next(file).strip().split(',')]                                                            
>>> for line in file: 
...:     for i, field in enumerate(line.strip().split(',')): 
...:         data[i][1].append(field) 
...:                                                                                                                   
>>> data = dict(data)                                                                                                  
>>> data                                                                                                               
{'first_name': ['tom', 'tom'], 'last_name': ['hanks', 'cruise']}
```

This is more of a programming exercise than a solution you should use in the real world. It's not robust at all and will fail for all kinds of common cases, such as having quoted fields containing commas in the csv file.

---

With `csv`, for other readers:

```
>>> import csv                                                                                                         
>>> reader = csv.reader(file) # assume fresh StringIO instance
>>> dict(zip(next(reader), zip(*reader)))                                                                              
{'first_name': ('tom', 'tom'), 'last_name': ('hanks', 'cruise')}
```

(Use `dict(zip(next(reader), map(list, zip(*reader))))` if having lists as values is important.)

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I'd go with `pandas` or `csv` but this is fairly easy to implement without any imports:

```
header = None
data = {}
for line in myfile:
    lstrip = line.strip().split(",")
    if not header:
        header = lstrip
        data = {k: [] for k in header}
    else:
        for i, value in enumerate(lstrip):
            data[header[i]].append(value)

print(data)
#{'first_name': ['tom', 'tom'], 'last_name': ['hanks', 'cruise']}
```

Comment: The only thing I'd do differently is create an iterator for `myfile` and use `next` to get the header row, and then iterate through normally after that so you wouldn't have to check a condition on each loop.

Comment: If `myfile` is a file-like object, it should already be an iterator.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds `myfile` is an iterator, but yeah generally I agree